# Межкомпонентная связь React: как передавать данные между компонентами?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

Здравствуйте! Вопрос касается связи между компонентами React,а именно: передача данных из одного компонента в другой.

Пусть есть страница `<Layout/>`, у которой есть массив объектов `items`. Для каждого элемента `items` создается компонент `<Item />`:

Код Layout.jsx:

```
class Layout extends Component {
  renderItems() {
    var items = [
      {name: 'Ivan', _id: '1'},
      {name: 'Petya', _id: '2'}
    ];

    return items.map( (each) => {
      return (
        <Item each={each} />
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <main> {this.renderItems} <main>
    );
  }
}
```

Код Item.jsx:

```
class Item extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.each.name}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Пусть теперь я хочу реализовать по щелчку на каждый `<Item />`вывод в консоль его `_id`. Сделать это внутри самого `<Item />` не составляет никакого труда:

Новый код Item.jsx:

```
class Item extends Component {
  printId() {
    console.log(this.props.each._id);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={ this.props.printId.bind(this) }>
        {this.props.each.name}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Но как быть, если нужно реализовать кнопку "Показать _id" снаружи, то есть в `<Layout />` ?

Допустим, внутри каждого `<Item/>` добавим `checkbox`. Если этот чекбокс отмечен галочкой как `selected`, то при нажатии кнопки 'Показать _id' в консоль выводятся `_id` всех отмеченных `Item`ов.

Но как передать `_id` отмеченных `Item`ов в `<Layout />` ?

Заранее благодарен за ответы.

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html

Comment: @AlexeyTen спасибо большое! сам не догадался поискать по запросу child-parent. сейчас разберусь и оформлю ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ нашелся сразу в [документации](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html), спасибо @AlexeyTen за наводку. Пришлось помучиться, однако решение готов и оно ниже.

При вызове функции из компонента `someFunction.bind(this)` мы можем передавать любое количество аргументов: `someFunction.bind(this, arg1, arg2, ...)`. В этом и заключается ответ.

Для примера выше: добавим функцию `printId` в компонент `<Layout />` и навесим на компонент `<Item />` вызов `printId` по  событию `onClick`. В качестве аргумента в функцию будем передавать текущий _id элемента. Новый код Layout.jsx:

```
class Layout extends Component {
  printId(id)
    console.log(id);

  renderItems() {
    var items = [
      {name: 'Ivan', _id: '1'},
      {name: 'Petya', _id: '2'}
    ];

    return items.map( (each) => {
      const eachId = each._id;
      return (
        <Item onClick={this.printId.bind(this, eachId)} each={each} />
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <main> {this.renderItems} <main>
    );
  }
}
```

Однако, код выше не будет работать. Причина в том, что `<Item />` это не настоящий DOM-элемент, соответственно и события `OnClick` у него быть не может. В строке `<Item onClick={this.printId.bind(this, eachId)} />`  `onCLick` является обычным `props`. Для того, чтобы этот код работал, как ожидается, нужно внутри компонента `<Item />` у настоящего DOM-элемента прописать передачу настоящему `onClick` нашу функцию из `props`:

```
class Item extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.props.onClick}>
        {this.props.each.name}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Теперь все работает как надо.