# Как передать данные из одного компонента в другой?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Есть код, который выводит посты и по клику на пост показывает его полное содержимое.

```
import React from "react";


type respX = {
    "id": any,
    "userId": any,
    "title": any,
    "body": any,
}

interface PropsI {
}

interface StateI {
    data: respX[];
    changedBody: string
    changedTitle: string
}

export class ComponentPostList extends React.Component<PropsI, StateI> {

    state: StateI = {data: [], changedBody: '', changedTitle: 'Click to choose article'}

    async getPostById(id: any) {
        const myResponse = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`);
        const myJson = await myResponse.json();
        this.setState({changedBody: myJson.body, changedTitle: myJson.title});
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        const response = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/`);
        const json = await response.json();
        this.setState({data: json});
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div className="About">
                <div className="content">
                    <div className="title">{this.state.changedTitle}</div>
                    <div className="article">{this.state.changedBody}</div>
                </div>
                {this.state.data.map(el => (
                    <li onClick={e => this.getPostById(el.id)} key={el.id}>
                        {el.title}
                    </li>
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Как правильно передать данные из одного компонента в другой? Чтобы рендер заголовков постов был в одном компоненте,а уже полное содержимое поста в другом компоненте. Эти компоненты находятся на одном уровне:

```
<ComponentPostList  data={data} onClick=(getPostById) />
<ComponentArticle post={post} />
```

Comment: Похожий [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/549974/195483)

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо создать родительский компонент, например, `Posts`, который будет визуализировать компоненты `ComponentPostList` и `ComponentArticle`. В компоненте `Posts` следует реализовать логику загрузки данных и обработки щелчка по посту. Также в состоянии компонента `Posts` должен храниться текущий отображаемый пост (или значение `null`, если ничего отображать не надо). Компонент `Posts` после загрузки данных должен передавать их дочернему компоненту `ComponentPostList` для визуализации. Также из компонента `Posts` в компонент `ComponentPostList` надо передать функцию обработки щелчков. Кроме того, из компонента `Posts` в компонент `ComponentArticle` следует передать содержимое отображаемого поста.
Таким образом, код вызова дочерних компонентов из компонента `Posts` будет похож на следующий:

```
<ComponentPostList data={data} onClick={() => this.getPostById} />
<ComponentArticle post={post} />
```

Answer (score 0):

не углубляясь к код, ответ:

- через общего родителя. он будет хранить состояние, а манипулировать данными можно через **всплытие/поднятие состояния**. ссылка на документацию [здесь](https://ru.react.js.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).
- через `<Context>`. это по сути, такой же подход, как и 1, но более красивее. родитель будет хранить и раздавать своё состояние, а любые дочерние(!) компоненты могут на это состояние подписываться.
- state management (к примеру, **redux**). позволяет хранить состояние всего приложение отдельно и независимо от всего

плюс я заметил, что Вы вешаете обработчики событий на все, созданные Вами `<li>`, элементы. вместо этого можно повесить один обработчик на родителя в целях производительности.