# Как передавать данные между компонентами в React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Пытаюсь понять как передать данные из одного компонента React в другой, но столкнулся с проблемой, что в Интернете, люди которые учат этому, используют примитивную систему без Router, что осложняет мою задачу.
Есть компонент один:

```
    export const MainPage = () => {
    return (
        <form>
        <input type="text"></input>
        <input type="submit"></input>
        </form>
    )
}
```

И есть компонент два:

```
    export const ItemPage = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>
            </h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

В компоненте один есть простейший инпут для ввода данных, а в компоненте 2 есть заголовок. Нужно чтобы данные инпута из компонента 1 передались в заголовок в компоненте 2 И естественно происходил переход в компонент 2 как при нажатии на ссылку (редирект), таким образом будет совершена передача данных, что мне и нужно. Но как же это сделать?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Межкомпонентная связь React: как передавать данные между компонентами?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/549974/%d0%9c%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8c-react-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8)